# email template in django

Tags: python, django, email

I created a email template in html im sending the email using below view which is working fine. But when i receive the email its desplaying in RAW html format. may i know what is the error.

```
def confirmed_email_notification(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Sends an email notification to the shop owner when a new order is
    completed.
    """
    print "EMAIL NOTIFICATION "
    subject_template_name = 'shop_simplenotifications/confirmed_subject.txt'
    body_template_name = 'shop_simplenotifications/confirmed_body.html'
    request = kwargs.get('request')
    order = kwargs.get('order')
    subject = loader.render_to_string(
        subject_template_name,
        RequestContext(request, {'order': order})
    )
    subject = subject.join(subject.splitlines())
    body = loader.render_to_string(
        body_template_name,
        RequestContext(request, {'order': order})
    )
    from_email = getattr(settings, 'SN_FROM_EMAIL',
                         settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL)
    owners = getattr(settings, 'SN_OWNERS', settings.ADMINS)
    send_mail(subject, body, from_email,
              [owner[1] for owner in owners], fail_silently=False)
    print body
    print [owner[1] for owner in owners]
confirmed.connect(confirmed_email_notification)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using django 1.7, you can pass the html version of your message to `send_mail()` as the `html_message` argument, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#send-mail

Else you can either use the `EmailMultiAlternatives` class as documented here :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

or use the `EmailMessage` class and set the `content_subtype` attribute to "html".

Just a side note: I really doubt `subject.join(subject.splitlines())` do what you expect:

```
>>> subject = "hello Huston\nWe have a\nproblem"
>>> print subject.join(subject.splitlines())
hello Hustonhello Huston
We have a
problemWe have ahello Huston
We have a
problemproblem
>>>
```